# Armory cannot find bitcoin installation in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, armory

I installed `Bitcoin Core version v0.11.2.0-g7e27892 (64-bit)`
at `/usr/bin/bitcoin-qt`.

After that I installed `armory 0.93.3-beta-e59e10d38c`.

When I launch armory it says "cannot find bitcoin installation".
I go to `File > Settings` and set "Bitcoin install dir" to `/usr/bin`.

Yet armory keeps repeating that msg.
Is it a bug?

I’m running `Ubuntu 14.04 64bit`.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Bitcoin install dir" to `/usr/bin/bitcoin-qt`?

Comment: @Murch: yes, i did

Comment: I mean, in armory? Because you wrote you set it to `/usr/bin` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you need to copy both "bitcoin-qt" and "bitcoind" files into the installation directory and make them executable (chmod 755 bitcoin*) then try installing in armory.
check this link:
[armory FAQ](https://www.bitcoinarmory.com/troubleshooting/#armory-cant-find-my-bitcoin-installation-but-i-know-its-installed)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably install bitcoind as well

```
sudo apt-get install bitcoind
```

[Here](https://www.bitcoinarmory.com/troubleshooting/#armory-cant-find-my-bitcoin-installation-but-i-know-its-installed) you can find more details

Comment: You should probably elaborate on this answer a bit more.  It helps to explain why this solution works, especially when there are different answers already posted.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a very newbie and I don't know more details but, this is what helped me to solve my case. I've added the source of my answer.